# c++: Access to members of a class that contains the class that wants the access

Tags: c++, scoping

Is it possible in c++ to modify a member of a class A that "surrounds" the class B (is in the "upper" scope) besides using a reference of the "surrounding class"?

code is here: http://pastebin.com/iEEu9iZG

The goal is to modify the `GFullScreen` variable with the same value of the fullscreen variable. I know that I can pass a pointer of `GFullScreen` or a reference of the whole Game class.. Is there another way to access to it? which one is more efficient?

Comment: Please provide sample code of what you've tried. This will better explain what you've attempted and we can better guide you.

Comment: ok I'm going to add some general code :)

Answer (score 2):

No.
It would have broken encapsulation horribly. And reference would have needed to be stored somewhere anyway, implicitly or explicitly - how else could you remember this relation?

Comment: Just to be sure - you are speaking about scenario where instance of one class is a member variable of another one or about putting ones definition inside of another? My answer is related to first case.

Answer (score 2):

If the member is `static` **and** `public` (or if `B` or the member function in `B` accessing the variable is a `friend` of `A`), then yes.

In every other case, no.

The reason is that B does not have an is-a relation to A, thus you need either an object (reference or pointer), or whatever you try to access must be `static`.

**EDIT:**
Just for fun, it is possible to make it *look* as if this was possible, by giving B a has-a relationship to A:

```
class A
{
    int a;

public:
    struct B;
};

class A::B : private A
{
    void foo() { A::a = 1; }
};
```

But of course I'm cheating here... this works because (and only because) every `B` has-a `A`, you only don't see it at once.

Comment: It's private and not static so the answer is no.. kk

Comment: Sort of not really... see my answer ;)

Comment: @void-pointer: Well ok, you can of course access pretty much any location in memory with a pointer, but I assume the question was about something that is legitimate and well-defined. Casting `this` to `char*`, incrementing it, and using it to access "some data that follows" is not something I'd consider very safe (apart from being totally UB, think of little details like alignment). My point is, declaring B inside A does little other than declare B in A's namespace. It does not make B an A, nor put B inside A, nor magically create some kind of link.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access members of class A using a reference of class B if class B is defined inside class A. You could only do this if Class B was inherited from class A. In that case, using a reference of type B,  you would be able to access public and protected members of A.

Comment: hi, I put some example code.. I'm not inheriting but I'm passing the reference anyway

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Note that the nested union is required to be at least 1 byte long, so an offset needs to be given to strcpy. Also, the behavior of this program is implementation-dependent and is more of a hack for demonstration purposes, though in practice I'd expect it to work predictably with any modern C++ compiler.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct _a
{
        union _b {
                void mutate()
                {
                        strcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this) + 1, "Goodbye, World!");
                }
        } b;
        char buf[256];

        _a() { strcpy(buf, "Hello, World!"); }
} a;

int main()
{
        std::cout << a.buf << "\n";
        a.b.mutate();
        std::cout << a.buf << std::endl;
        return 0;
};
```

My point is that with knowledge of C/C++ internals, you can devise some platform-dependent hacks that are often useful and necessary. This one isn't however, so I'd highly advise against actually using the code given above to accomplish common tasks.

Comment: ps I'd like to create my game platform indipendent so I think this is not my case :(

Comment: To be clear, you'd most probably NEVER want to use the code that I gave in my answer--it was only for demonstration. In C++, the public keyword is used like a label; also, you ought to look up initializer lists.

Comment: Although this is of the "oh please don't..." category, I feel compelled to upvote this example, just because the idea is so crazy :-)

Comment: I think this needs some multiple implementation inheritance messed into, for even more implementation-specific fun ;)

Comment: @void-pointer: your solution almost perfectly matches your nick ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java (nonstatic) inner classes, C++ inner classes doesn't provide any hidden reference to outer class instance (C++ rarely does something hidden, except of vtable), so you need to provide such a reference by yourself, if needed.

Comment: As I did.. ok.. I was just wondering about the efficiency of this type of passage. Is it right? is it better to do in another way?

Comment: @Mario: I doubt it is essentially better way to do it. Perhaps, some  template pattern may partially automate this work... as to efficiency, i suppose it's (runtime) efficient enough.

Comment: uhm.. yes. I was just thinking that another option could be to return a value to the "containing" class and basing on that modifying the GFullScreen variable. Probably, in terms of efficiency it's the same.. what do you think?

Comment: @Mario: However if the instance of inner class apperas only as a field in outer class, it is possible to use CONTAINING_RECORD macro or it variations to cast to outer class from the field pointer. But it is rather a hack (and is not noncompliant with standard in some cases), so it is better to use inheritance in this case.

Comment: uhm.. inheritance? in my case I don't know it it's feasible

Comment: @Mario: in the particular case you A constructor may accept a refernce to fs and store it, so it may modify it later. You should also be care about lifetimes of the objects, i.e. be shure that Game  will not disappear before any A instance. As to inheritance, it may be used only if there are strictly 1 instance of A per Game, it is not probably your case

Comment: uhm yes, sort it then. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

So I see no one has answered this with a best practice example, I will give one here:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//before includes:
class A;

//B.h
class B{
    public:
        B(A *);
        void test();
        A *parent;
};

//A.h
class A{
    public:
        A();
        ~A();

        B *b;
        void test();

        int n;
};

//B.cpp
B::B(A *a){
    parent = a;
}

void B::test(){
    cout << parent->n;
}

//A.cpp
A::A(){
    n = 404;
    b = new B(this);
}
A::~A(){
    delete b;
}
void A::test(){
    b->test();
}

//example.cpp
int main( int argc, char **argv){
    A a;
    a.test();
}
```

You will see that you need to pass the context yourself to the contained class to access the containing class. There is no other way, than by passing the context yourself to the class.